# How to enable let's encrypt SSL for multiple domains in a single project in VestaCP?

Tags: laravel, ssl, lets-encrypt, vesta

I have a laravel-powered website `site.com` with let's encrypt SSL enabled via VestaCP.
Now I want to add also `site.id` and `site.ru` to be directed into same project base and have the SSL enabled on them too.

I've tried to put `site.id` and `site.ru` as aliases of `site.com` and without SSL it works. However if I try to disable and re-enable the let's encrypt certificate to trigger generation of certificate for all 3 domains, I get `Let's encrypt 400` error.
Maybe it's somehow possible to get done via SSH commands? 
Or maybe I can set 3 separate `www` domains in vestacp and then via SSH configure nginx configuration to direct them all into one codebase folder?

My last resort would be to set 3 **www** domains in vesta with separate codebases and SSL certificates, but single DB. It just seems very inefficient to go this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a certificate for each unique domain that needs to be available via SSL. You don't need to have separate code bases, you just need to ask for a cert for all the sites.

```
certbot-auto -d site.id -d site.ru -d site.com
```

Comment: So instead of using the GUI from VestaCP, I use the steps of certbot via SSH and can request multiple cers using your command, correct?